# Safari / iOs responsive

Tags: ios, iphone, css, responsive

I have problem with my website.

In my "toggle device" toolbar I picked the responsive option for iPhone 7 Plus, Galaxy 8, etc.
My website does look good but when I open my web on an iPhone(7+/6S+) my website doesn't work like I want. I don't know why it doesn't look the way I want it to. On Galaxy S8 website look nice.

Is it a problem with Safari?

I used:

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) 
{
::i-block-chrome, Class Name {your styles}
}

@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { @media {

    .safari_only { 

        color:#0000FF; 
        background-color:#CCCCCC; 

    }
}}
```

Does somebody know how to help me?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment since I don't have the permission, so I will be talking with you through the usage of this answer. First of all, I need your HTML code. Stack Overflow is not a website where we do the coding for you. Without seeing what is wrong (please provide screenshots of what you want vs. what you are seeing) I cannot help you.

Based on your question, I am confused by what you mean by "responsive." Are you making the website through the use of another program such as Adobe Muse? If so, try talk about it on their forums rather than here. Please update your question with a screenshot and the HTML code so that I can help you.

Once I understand the question and can figure out the answer, I will remove all the text in this answer and replace with the true answer.